# Is there a clever way to restrict the expansion of water in a partially filled barrel to the top?

Tags: freezing

I have an application for a cold room for a few weeks in late spring.

If I freeze a partially filled barrel, typically it will initially freeze at the top, then freeze  in. The result is bulge in the ice in the center at both ends of the water slug.  Usually a barrel will survive once, but the barrel is deformed, and a second event breaks the bottom.

The situation is worse if the barrel is on the ground.  The thermal coupling between the barrel and ground causes that end to freeze more slowly, so the bulk of expansion is at that end.

Can this be reversed?  What would be the effect of adding 2-3 inches of styrofoam peanuts to the barrel, and elevate the barrel off the ground?  The idea is that heat loss is reduced on the top face.  The bulk of the freezing now happens on the sides and bottom.  The bulk of the bulge is now at the air interface at the top end of the barrel.

Will this work?  How much foam do I need?

Comment: Most substances expand (become less dense) with increasing temperature, but water does the opposite just above the freezing point.

Comment: I get that.  Water is at its densest about 4C.  Below that you start to get ephemeral linkages between water molecules that take up more room.  The trick is to direct the expansion in one direction. Ice doesn't begin to deform until pressures of about 3-4 bar.  If the top ice is enough thinner than the bottom ice, then all the expansion is into the head space in the barrel.